# TransactionManagementError when editing a django-cms page

Tags: python, django, sqlite, atomic, django-cms

I was about to ask a question and found a solution just before posting :)

**The problem:**

I was trying to setup [django-cms](https://www.django-cms.org/en/) for a simple app and I was getting a `TransactionManagementError` when trying to edit a page on the frontend.

```
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError
TransactionManagementError: This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active.
```

I am currently using `sqlite` and I needed to add `'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True` because I was getting this:

```
TransactionManagementError: Your database backend doesn't behave properly when autocommit is off. Turn it on before using 'atomic'.
```

Database settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True
    }
}
```

The versions I was using

```
Django==1.6.5
django-cms==3.0.2
```

Here is the traceback I was getting:

```
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError
TransactionManagementError: This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active.

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/Users/gableroux/.virtualenvs/adls-si/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
return self.application(environ, start_response)
File "/Users/gableroux/.virtualenvs/adls-si/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 206, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/Users/gableroux/.virtualenvs/adls-si/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 194, in get_response
response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
File "/Users/gableroux/.virtualenvs/adls-si/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 229, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/Users/gableroux/.virtualenvs/adls-si/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 5, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users/gableroux/.virtualenvs/adls-si/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 112, in get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/gableroux/.virtualenvs/adls-si/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 371, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/gableroux/.virtualenvs/adls-si/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/admin/settingsadmin.py", line 21, in wrapper
return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/gableroux/.virtualenvs/adls-si/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 99, in _wrapped_view
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/gableroux/.virtualenvs/adls-si/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 52, in _wrapped_view_func
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/gableroux/.virtualenvs/adls-si/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 198, in inner
return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/gableroux/.virtualenvs/adls-si/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 29, in _wrapper
return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/gableroux/.virtualenvs/adls-si/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 99, in _wrapped_view
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/gableroux/.virtualenvs/adls-si/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 25, in bound_func
return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/Users/gableroux/.virtualenvs/adls-si/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 430, in inner
with self:
File "/Users/gableroux/.virtualenvs/adls-si/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 422, in __enter__
self.entering(self.using)
File "/Users/gableroux/.virtualenvs/adls-si/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 483, in entering
enter_transaction_management(using=using)
File "/Users/gableroux/.virtualenvs/adls-si/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 70, in enter_transaction_management
get_connection(using).enter_transaction_management(managed, forced)
File "/Users/gableroux/.virtualenvs/adls-si/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 287, in enter_transaction_management
self.validate_no_atomic_block()
File "/Users/gableroux/.virtualenvs/adls-si/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 367, in validate_no_atomic_block
"This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active.")
TransactionManagementError: This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active.
The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only had to update from `django-cms==3.0.2` to `django-cms==3.0.3` and the problem was gone. This could help someone.

I am not sure what the problem was about exactly. I was also getting `<class 'cms.models.titlemodels.Title'> has not been registered with django-reversion` with reversion, [See this issue](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/3211) and upgrading to 3.0.3 seemed to fix this too.

Comment: I've got the same issue and have been running 3.0.3 since it was released. I think there's a deeper issue here, but as of yet do not know what.

Comment: Which version of `django` are you using?

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken. I'm on two almost identical projects & although I upgraded one, the guys where this happened were still on 3.0.2! I upgraded & the transaction fixes in that version resolved it :)